# Evaluate $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(nx)}{2^n}$ where $\cos x = \frac15$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, complex-numbers

Evaluate 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\cos(nx)}{2^n}$$
where $\cos x = \frac{1}{5}$.

This is a complex number question. But I don’t know where to start. Maybe need to use the DeMoivre’s Theorem?

Comment: Are you sure it is $\cos(nx)$ and not $\cos^n x$?

Comment: Toby, yes, it’s nx

Comment: Note that $\cos nx$ is the real part of $e^{inx}$ for $x$ real.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the following auxiliar sum: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty i\dfrac{\sin(nx)}{2^{n}}$, and use that $e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$ to get: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{\cos(nx)}{2^{n}}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty i\dfrac{\sin(nx)}{2^{n}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{\cos(nx)}{2^{n}}+i\dfrac{\sin(nx)}{2^{n}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{\cos(nx)+i\sin(nx)}{2^{n}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{e^{inx}}{2^{n}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\dfrac{e^{ix}}{2})^{n}=\dfrac{1}{1-e^{ix}/2}=\dfrac{2}{2-e^{ix}}=\dfrac{2}{2-\cos(x)-i\sin(x)}=\dfrac{2}{((2-\cos(x))-i\sin(x))}\dfrac{(2-\cos(x))+i\sin(x)}{((2-\cos(x))+i\sin(x))}=\dfrac{4-2\cos(x)+2i\sin(x)}{(2-\cos(x))^{2}+\sin^{2}(x)}=\dfrac{4-2\cos(x)+2i\sin(x)}{4-4\cos(x)+\cos^{2}(x)+\sin^{2}(x)}=\dfrac{4-2\cos(x)+2i\sin(x)}{5-4\cos(x)}=\dfrac{4-2\cos(x)}{5-4\cos(x)}+i\dfrac{2\sin(x)}{5-4\cos(x)}$

and comparing imaginary and real parts with $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{\cos(nx)}{2^{n}}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty i\dfrac{\sin(nx)}{2^{n}}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{\cos(nx)}{2^{n}}+i\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{\sin(nx)}{2^{n}}$ 
to obtain: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{\sin(nx)}{2^{n}}=\dfrac{2\sin(x)}{5-4\cos(x)}$ and $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{\cos(nx)}{2^{n}}=\dfrac{4-2\cos(x)}{5-4\cos(x)}$

Comment: `\cos` and `\sin` can be used for the cleaner $\cos$ and $\sin$.

Comment: Some other things (which might be matter of personal preference): You can choose whether to use $\cos(nx)$ or $\cos nx$, similarly you can prefer $\sum_{n=0}^\infty$ or $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

$\frac {\cos (nx)} {2^{n}}$ is the real part of $(\frac {e^{ix}} 2)^{n}$. Thus you only have to sum a geometric series.

Answer (score 0):

If $S=\sum_{r=0}^\infty y^r\cos r x$

Using scale of relation from [this](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Ph49AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA239&lpg=PA239&dq=%22scale%20of%20relation%22%20hobson&source=bl&ots=D3atKAXOUI&sig=ACfU3U3V8ZtR7fOOEDzCsZmpjxJj67_QuQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiuk9bk6LHkAhW28XMBHYmIAKEQ6AEwDHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22scale%20of%20relation%22%20hobson&f=false) or $\#187$ of [this](https://archive.org/details/treatiseonplanet00hobs/page/238)(downloadable)

$$(1-2y\cos x+y^2)S$$

$$=1+y\cos x+y^2\cos2x+y^3\cos3x+\cdots$$

$$-2y\cos x-2y^2\cos^2x-2y^3\cos2x\cos x-2y^4\cos3x\cos x-\cdots$$

$$+y^2+y^3\cos x+y^4\cos2x+y^5\cos3x+\cdots$$

$$=1+y(-\cos x)+y^2(\cos2x-2\cos^2x+1)+y^3(\cos3x-2\cos3x\cos x+\cos x)+\cdots$$

$$\implies S=\dfrac{1-y\cos x}{1-2y\cos x+y^2}$$

Here $2y=1$