# Prove that $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{\cos(k\cos^{-1}x)}{x^k}=\frac {\sin(n\cos^{-1}x)}{x^{n-1}\sqrt[2]{1-x^2}} $

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

By considering $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (1+i\tan\theta)^k,$ how do I prove that

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{\cos(k\cos^{-1}x)}{x^k}=\frac {\sin(n\cos^{-1}x)}{x^{n-1}\sqrt[2]{1-x^2}}$$ for $0<x<1$

I am completely clueless about how to approach this problem

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3340563/evaluate-sum-limits-n-0-infty-frac-cosnx2n-where-cos-x-frac/3341802#3341802

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(1+i\tan(\theta))^k=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{[\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)]^k}{\cos^k(\theta)}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\cos(k\theta)+i\sin(k\theta)}{\cos^k(\theta)}$$

The first sum is given by geometric series

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(1+i\tan(\theta))^k=\frac{(1+i\tan(\theta))^n-1}{1+i\tan(\theta)-1}=\frac{\cos(n\theta)-\cos^n(\theta)+i\sin(n\theta)}{i\cos^n(\theta)\tan(\theta)}$$

Taking real parts gives

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\cos(k\theta)}{\cos^k(\theta)}=\frac{\sin(n\theta)}{\cos^{n-1}(\theta)\sin(\theta)}$$

Now just substitute $x=\cos(\theta)$ and you will have your result.

Comment: But how do i solve the other side ?

Comment: It's a geometric series.

Comment: I used $S_n$ formula, but i always stop at a dead end. Please post the answer if you are able to solve this

Comment: Updated @HarshitGupta

Comment: Thanks man @SimplyBeautifulArt but there is a slight calculation mistake in 2nd row last equation $-1$ should be replaced with $cos^n\theta$