# Sum of the series $1-2r\cos~\theta +3r^2 \cos~2\theta -4r^3\cos~3\theta+\dots$..

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Sum of the series 
>   $$1-2r\cos~\theta +3r^2 \cos~2\theta -4r^3\cos~3\theta+\dots\qquad |r|<1.$$

I don't know how to find sum other than for geometric series and this is not geometric.

Comment: Set $$\theta=x+\pi$$ and then integrate both sides with respect to $\theta$ and use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3340563/evaluate-sum-limits-n-0-infty-frac-cosnx2n-where-cos-x-frac/3341802?r=SearchResults#3341802

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to combine$$\sum_{n\ge0}(n+1)z^n=\frac{d}{dz}\sum_{n\ge0}z^{n+1}=\frac{d}{dz}\frac{z}{1-z}=\frac{d}{dz}\frac{1}{1-z}=\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}$$with$$\sum_{n\ge0}(n+1)(-r)^n\cos n\theta=\Re\sum_{n\ge0}(n+1)(-r\exp i\theta)^n=\Re\frac{1}{(1+r\exp i\theta)^2}\\=\Re\frac{(1+r\exp -i\theta)^2}{(1+r^2+2r\cos\theta)^2}=\frac{1+2r\cos\theta+r^2\cos 2\theta}{(1+r^2+2r\cos\theta)^2}.$$